# Allow a user with a reputation lower than 20 to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

A user with a reputation lower than 20 points is not allowed to chat.

Would not be good if those users could be invited in chat by users who have the privilege of chatting? I am suggesting this because, when users are not allowed to chat, comments become a discussion between the users who asked the question, and one or more users.

Comment: It would need to be a network-wide decision, as chat is another site. As such, it can't be decided here, only on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). and if you will ask there, it will be closed as a duplicate of [meta-tag:feature-request] [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Allow inviting people with rep < 20 to private chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat)

Comment: I did'n see that, though I did'n try the solution but yes this question is duplicate, thanks @Mołot

Comment: Not technically a duplicate, as technically we don't have cross-site duplicates. But there was a feature request to allow some posts from main meta be available on all metas. I guess there was feature request from pretty much anything already :P

Comment: I am trying to find a canonical answer to this.

Comment: Related from MSO today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208234/chatting-to-users-with-limited-rep